# Can I always show permission dialog in Facebook application when user logins?

Tags: facebook, logging, permissions

I'm trying to write application for user login to website via Facebook. When user is logging in, he's redirected to http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&state=STATE, then sees confirmation dialog to use permissions and all goes well. But then FB somehow remembers this application and never asks for permissions confirmation again when user opens this url. Is there any way to always show this dialog? I could do it in Twitter, but couldn't found the answer for Facebook.

Comment: It's only way to change user except for opening Facebook page and logging out there.

Comment: 1. Users on Facebook not allowed to have more than one account. 2. You can always use `FB.logout` in JS-SDK or `getLogoutUrl` in PHP-SDK (something similar in other SDK should be present as well) to log user out before showing login dialog

Comment: Yes, but users of my site may log in by other facebook account. And I don't want them to logout if they don't want to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down-voted. Maybe the downvoters thought the answer was obvious and that's why? The scenario itself seems legit to me. Multiple people might use one computer, logging into their own facebook accounts. One person might end up using another person's facebook account to log into a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want this for some reason, uninstall the app from the user's account with a HTTP DELETE request to `/USER_ID/permissions` using your [app access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/authentication#applogin).
The next time they come back they'll need to re-authorise the app.

Otherwise, no, there's no way that I'm aware of apart from the [reauthentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reauthentication/) to force the auth dialog to appear, but bear in mind that the reauthentication flow may prompt the user to re-enter their Facebook password even if they're already logged into Facebook, so it adds extra friction to the process

Answer (score 1):

Instead of showing the Facebook OAuth dialog, you could also show the user a page on your application that has some information about the Facebook account that is going to be used (picture/name etc), to log into it. That way, if they like they can choose to log out and re-authenticate or continue knowing they have the right account.